# SQL performance of filter in join vs in results where

Tags: sql, performance, query-optimization, sql-tuning

I need to join 2 tables but one of them has a constant filter that has to be applied, my question is what option is better in terms of performance:

1. Having the constant filter on the "FROM" and setting an alias like this:

   ```
    SELECT <result fields> 
    FROM 
        (SELECT <table A fields> 
         FROM filtered_table 
         WHERE field = value) AS A 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB ON A.id = tableB.id
   ```
2. Setting the filter in the `WHERE` of the main query:

   ```
   SELECT <result fields> 
   FROM filtered_table AS A 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB ON A.id = tableB.id 
   WHERE a.field = value
   ```

Comment: I am pretty sure any modern DBMS will run both queries in exactly the same way. But if you want to be sure, check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html)

Answer (score 0):

Most databases will treat the two forms the same -- they are logically the same and the optimizer knows this.

*Some* databases tend to materialize subqueries.  MySQL is one of these.  In that database, the subquery would probably be more expensive, because it writes out the subquery.

I would recommend writing the code without a subquery.  It is both simpler to write and read and it should never have worse performance than the subquery method.